# Resize numpy.memmap inplace

Tags: python, numpy, memory, numpy-memmap

The code of resizing **`numpy.memmap`** seems work but changes made by program don't saved.

```
def test_resize_inplace():

    fA = np.memmap('A_r.npy', dtype='uint8', mode='w+', shape=(3,12))

    print "fA"
    print fA

    fA[2][0] = 42

    # resize by creating new memmap
    new_fA = np.memmap('A_r.npy', mode='r+', dtype='uint8', shape=(20,12))

    print 'fA'
    print fA

    print 'new_fA'
    print new_fA
```

also when I try to take resizing procedure out it crushes python interpreter on line

```
print new_fA
```

the code below:

```
def resize_memmap(fm,sz,tp):
    fm.flush()
    print fm.filename
    new_fm = np.memmap(fm.filename, mode='r+', dtype= tp, shape=sz)
    return new_fm

def test_resize_inplace():

    fA = np.memmap('A_r.npy', dtype='uint8', mode='w+', shape=(3,12))

    print "fA"
    print fA

    fA[2][0] = 42

    sz= (20,12)
    tp= 'uint8'

    new_fA= resize_memmap(fA,sz,type)
    new_fA[9][9]= 111

    print 'fA'
    print fA

    print 'new_fA'
    print new_fA
```

---

**UPDATE:**
I tried **`.flush()`**

```
def test_memmap_flush():
    fA = np.memmap('A_r.npy', dtype='uint8', mode='w+', shape=(3,12))

    print "fA"
    print fA

    fA[2][0] = 42

    fA.flush()

# fB = np.memmap('A_r.npy', dtype='uint8', mode='w+', shape=(3,12)) #fails
fB = np.memmap('A_r.npy', dtype='uint8', mode='r+', shape=(3,12))

    print "fB"
    print fB

    print "done"
```

but I don't understand why I can't have **`w+`** mode?

> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w+b') or filename: 'A_r.npy'

---

**UPDATE:**

ok, I understand. **`w+`** for creation and **`r+`** for read and write.

Answer (score 0):

The file is probably not flushed between the accesses. Try passing memmap a file object you load in a with block:

```
with open('A_r.npy', 'w') as f:
    fA = np.memmap(f, ...
with open('A_r.npy', 'r') as f:
    fA = np.memmap(f, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

### <sup>Answer:</sup> Why the `IO Error: [Errno 22]` appears?

First I have to admit that for about a six months this caused me some minor troubles and I have resorted to a manual hack for this.

Finally I have found the root-cause.

This error **appear only in Windows** <sub>( Unix did not yield the exception on this )</sub>
 when the **`.memmap()`**-ed file has coincidentally been still opened under another file-handle.

```
del aMMAP # first ( does .flush() before closing the underlying fileHandle
#         # next, mmap again, with adjustments you need
aMMAP = np.memmap( ... )
```

---

<sub>Hope this helps
**[Credit goes to Michael Droettboom](https://github.com/spacetelescope/pyasdf/issues/100)**</sub>